# Python data transfer

Tags: python, sockets, networking, cluster-computing

I want develop a system where I can transfer some images and after run some algorithms on cluster.

My cluster job submitter should be able to connect for more than one user.

I read a little about paramiko but is necessary a ssh user and I don't want use it.

Other specifications, my client will send and receive the images.

Sockets is the best solution?

Anybody did something like this?

Thanks

João

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the following packages would probably do what you want

- Celery http://pypi.python.org/pypi/celery/2.1.4
- Parallel Python http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pp/1.6.0
- AsynQueue http://pypi.python.org/pypi/AsynQueue/0.3
- Pyro http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pyro4/4.2

Comment: How about something as simple as an HTTP library?